# Retrieve private class member name

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, metadata, annotation-processing

I am designing a Hibernate's entity Pre-Update Event Listener with Java 8.

I've created a **StateTracker** class that, from the *PreUpdateEvent*, gets the entity's new and old states and the parameters name. This class maps the parameters names to the corresponding pair of old and new states and a lazy evaluated *Boolean* **hasChanged** and make querying the map by key (which is of type *String*) available through a public method.

Problem is: I need to check if a specific property from an entity **A**, say it is named **var**, will have it's state changed by the update event. Naturally this can be done like this:

```
void foo(PreUpdateEvent event) {
    StateTracker stateTracker(event);
    if(stateTracker.isPropertyModified("var") {
        /* do stuff... */
    }
}
```

I know I can't always save the world, but if someone ever changes **var** name to ***catastrophe*** in **A**, then the above code will be broken, because even the smarter of the refactoring tools won't see that the *String* "var" is meant to represent the name of the parameter **var** (now ***catastrophe***).

I am accepting that there is no better way out of this situation, but I want to be sure that is no way to get a variable name through reflection or something.

Ideally, this would work like this:

```
void foo(PreUpdateEvent event) {
    StateTracker stateTracker(event);
    if(stateTracker.isPropertyModified(A.class.var.getName()) { // Magic!
        /* do stuff... */
    }
}
```

Maybe some wizardry in the field of annotation processing could perform such magic...

Comment: Best bet is to have a unit test ensure that the field name used is correct.

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem great suggestion, I'm going with unit tests

Answer (score 0):

Yes go through simply reflection, iterate through tabs, create a hashset key is the field name and value is value of field then each time iterate through your set and if the any item state changed/removed flag the entity as updated

Comment: or instead of value you can use a generated hash of value will be less memory consuming

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure it out how this solves the problem. I do not want to flag the entity as updated, I want to filter out relevant updates to the entity based on specific fields being updated. Creating a hashset won't put away the risk of someone modifying a field name and render code that uses the old name in StateTracker broken.